# Rackspace cloud windows server beta?

Tags: windows

Can I use Rackspace cloud servers for windows beta in a live production environment?

How reliable are beta? And is anyone using beta for live production here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a look tonight. Service does look pretty good and it is well priced. But there is such a big risk in putting customer websites on something that could be pulled any minute. So, it makes me wonder what anyone would use this service for while it's still in beta. In fact, it's pretty cheeky that rackspace charge for using something that we're essentially testing for them. It's tempting, but ask yourself this - what would your clients think if they knew about it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm more than a littel dogmatic about this but;

- Production Platform = Tested, stable code serving actual users,
- Reference Platform = Tested, stable code serving trial users.
- Test Platform = Not tested, hopefully stable code serving test users.
- Dev Platform = Not testable, potentially stable code serving dev users.
- 'Play' Platform = New stuff for geeks to mess with.

Nothing should jump more than one stage up the chain at a time.

So in my book running beta code in production would initiate an 'interesting' discussion, often requiring one party to update their resume :)

**Short answer - don't.**

Answer (score 0):

To quote from Rackspace's own FAQ:

> 5) Can I run production workloads on
>   Cloud Servers Windows during the beta
>   period?
>
> Because this is a beta offering, we do
>   not recommend running production
>   workloads or applications.
>
> *Source:* http://www.rackspacecloud.com/windows

So you *can* - but probably shouldn't.  I am running some public facing stuff from their Windows Cloud Servers and it's working great, but the stuff we're running is also beta.

Until they have their backup and imaging systems in place, I don't think you can use it for prod stuff.